# Speeding up a SQL query with indexes

Tags: sql-server, database, performance

I have a table called `Products`.

This table contains over 3 million entries. Every day there are approximately 5000 new entries. which only happens during the night in 2 minutes.

But this table gets queried every night maybe over 20 000 times with this query.

```
SELECT Price 
FROM Products 
WHERE Code = @code 
  AND Company = @company 
  AND CreatedDate = @createdDate
```

Table structure:

```
Code          nvarchar(50)
Company       nvarchar(10)
CreatedDate   datetime
```

I can see that this query takes about a second to return a result from `Products` table.

There is no `productId` column in the table as it is not needed. So there is no primary key in the table.

I would like to somehow improve this query to return the result faster.

I have never used indexes before. What would be the best way to use indexes on this table?

If I provide a primary key do you think it would speed up the query result? Keep in mind that I will still have to query the table by providing 3 parameters as

```
WHERE Code = @code 
  AND Company = @company 
  AND CreatedDate = @createdDate.
```

This is mandatory.

As I mentioned that the table gets new entries in 2 minutes every day during the night. How would this affect the indexes?

If I use indexes, which column would be the best to use and whether I should use clustered or non-clustered indexes?

Comment: find out missing indexes on the table using tuning advisor or Create Clustered Index on a column which will do more DML operations and Create Non-Clustered Index along with Covering Indexes

Comment: Do you get an index suggestion when you display the estimated execution plan of your query in SSMS?

Comment: I would put an NCI on `(CreatedDate, Company, Code) INCLUDE(Price)`.

Comment: "So there is no primary key in the table." - Every table should have a primary key even if it's just a surrogate key.  @wewesthemenace's index looks appropriate.

Comment: the query gets run through console application. never used execution plan in ssms @hatchet.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but would be explain your query a bit more. perhaps reply as an answer with query wewesthemenace

Comment: I will add a primary key in the table thanks Mitch Wheat and see the result.

Comment: Every table should have a clustered index, or at least in case the table gets updated / deleted, because that can cause serious fragmentation and wasted space in your table

Comment: Hello @akdurmus, here is a general tip for speeding up queries: In SQL Management Studio (SSMS) you can check the option "Show ACTUAL Execution Plan". (be sure it is actual, not planned) Then you start your query, and afterwards, you see the execution plan in a separate tab. You can see there what happens in your query, and why it is so slow. Also, the system can detect that an important index is missing, and it will show you the `create index` statement that will speed up the query.

Comment: PS: It really helps to learn to understand the execution plan and how indexes and tables work. You will see, it is not so much magic, but it is still important to understand how the mechanics work. Once you have the knowledge, you can get **unbelievable speeds** out of a database!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The *best* thing to do would depend on what other fields the table has and what other queries run against that table.

Without more details, a non-clustered index on (code, company, createddate) that included the "price" column will certainly improve performance.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_code_company_createddate
ON Products(code, company, createddate)
INCLUDE (price);
```

That's because if you have that index in place, then SQL will not access the actual table at all when running the query, as it can find all rows with a given "code, company, createddate" in the index and it will be able to do that really fast as the index allows precisely for fast access when using the fields that define the key, and it will also have the "price" value for each row.

Regarding the inserts, for each row added, SQL Server will have to add them to the index as well, so performance for inserts will be impacted. In think you should expect the gains on SELECT performance to outweigh the impact on the inserts, but you should test that.

Also, you will be using more space as the index will store all those fields for each row besides the space used by the original table.

As others have noted in the comments, adding a PK to your table (even if that means adding a ProductId column you don't actually *need*) might be a good idea as well.

Comment: If it was me, I would reverse the order: `CreatedDate,Company,Code`.

Comment: Cant believe this. The process speeded up like nitro. thanks a lot. yes as you have mentioned that inserting was taking around 2 minutes before and after creating the index it takes about 8  minutes. but select query is shorten from 2 hours to 5 minutes. cannot believe this :)

Comment: @akdurmus Now you see the magic of an index ;) Of course: If you have 3 Million records and NO index, then the database needs to **SCAN** the table; that means 3 million accesses, in average 1.5 million ! But if you have an index, then the database just needs **1 to 3** (!) disk accesses  ! An index works similar to the index in a book: You look up the first letter, then the 2nd, and then you are already there.

Comment: Adding this index will speed up Price UPDATE or will slow it down ?. Thank you.