# Speeding up [select * into table] across linked servers

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to copy a table with size ~50 million rows into another database on a link server. It does not have any indexes (although i wouldn't think that should make a difference). I've used the following query:

```
select * into [db2].[schema].[table_name] 
from 
openquery([linked_server_name],
'select * from [db1].[schema].[table_name]')
```

This took approximately 7 minutes.

This seems suspiciously long for what I intended to be a simple copy and paste. Am I missing something?

I need to run this on a regular basis and would ideally like to keep it as automated as possible (no manual copying tables across servers using SISS would be ideal)

Any ideas would be highly appreciated!

Thanks a bunch

Comment: It's better to have copy delta data. 7 min is not bad considering table copy is not file copy.

Answer (score 1):

There could be lots of different reasons at play here each having a cumulative effect on the 'slowness'.

Looking at the [wait states](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/) will be the first port of call.

Indexing ( at least on the select side ) isnt an issue here , there is no predicate used ( at to a lesser extent using all the columns ) therefore how would you expect an index to be helpful ??

I would say that number of rows is not a helpful metric...  How big in terms of MB / GB is the source data set ?  Use the "Include Client Statistics" in SSMS to get an accurate nummber.   Now, if that is 'big' how log does it take to drag a .zip file of the same size over the network ?

Answer (score 0):

Without the indexing of the table, the SELECT query is bound to be slow. Indexes help in improving the performance of the select query. The indexes slow down the INSERT queries as they have to add the data as well as index it simultaneously. On the contrary, the index creation boosts up the SELECT query.

Also, is your data copied transactional in nature or you can do away with dirty read? If dirty read is fine then you can use WITH(NOLOCK) in the SELECT query to avoid and transaction issues.

Comment: I don't think index make a difference for `SELECT * FROM ...`. Table without primary key even fast enough in such situation.

Comment: IMHO please refer to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856674/speeding-up-a-sql-query-with-indexes

Comment: Query in question don't have any filter.

Comment: A table without a clustered index having millions of records is like a heap table. So, even if you do not have any filters, still the performance of a heap table without any index is slower than a table having clustered index. Please refer to the following white paper [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917672.aspx#EFAA)

Comment: This article includes single row selection and range selection. Are they the same as full table selection?

Comment: I may be wrong in my understanding. So please correct me. On a heap table, the data pages won't be linked to each other and hence, traversing through the pages requires IAM lookup. But, if the table has a clustered index, that will not be required to have a IAM lookup.

Comment: Forward fetches are potentially an issue without a clustered index too, that's going to slow the procedure down considerably.

Comment: I think the best answer is to run the same select all on head and index. On my machine, I don't see any difference.

Comment: I agree, even I could not find any noticeable difference in performance of the whole table select query with millions of rows.